# What are the eventual consequences of being a narcissist?

Tags: social-psychology, personality, abnormal-psychology

A close question to what I am trying to ask is [Is there scientific evidence that narcissists cannot be treated?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/9970/is-there-scientific-evidence-that-narcissists-cannot-be-treated).

I was wondering what are the eventual consequences of being a narcissist? Is there any study that has been carried out in this perspective?

What I am looking for in fact is, if untreated, how narcissism would manifest itself as a chronic personality disorder. Do we have any understanding of how narcissism would progress like a behavioral disorder?

Comment: The term *progress* makes it sound more like a disease process than a personality disposition or set of coping mechanisms. Is the focus here on the change in the condition, or the change in circumstances and relationships?

Comment: Ideally both (in the condition as well as circumstances & relationships) would be good.